# SQL Server 2008 R2 / SUM costs of costs center

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have:

```
ReNr  |Hours|Costs|Cost Center|Change
12345 |1    |122,5|4711       |A
12345 |2    |245  |4711       |B
12345 |1    |122,5|4712       |C
12345 |1    |122,5|4712       |D
12345 |2    |245  |4712       |E
```

I Need the SUM of the costs by Cost Center, something like this:

```
ReNr     |Hours|Costs|Cost Center
12345    |3    |367,5|4711        
12345    |4    |490  |4712
```

I try to use a PIVOT:

```
SELECT  [ReNr]
       ,ISNULL([Hours], 0) AS [Hours]
       ,ISNULL([Cst2501], 0) AS [Cst2501]
       ,ISNULL([Cst2510], 0) AS [Cst2510]
       ,ISNULL([Cst2705], 0) AS [Cst2705]
       ,ISNULL([Cst5010], 0) AS [Cst5010]
       ,ISNULL([Cst7080], 0) AS [Cst7080]
       ,ISNULL([Cst7120], 0) AS [Cst7120]
       ,ISNULL([Cst7301], 0) AS [Cst7301]
FROM  
(
    SELECT  [ReNr]
           ,[Hours]
           ,[Costs]
           ,[CostCenter]
    FROM [dbo].[Abrechnungen]
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Costs])
    FOR [CostCenter] IN ([Cst2501], [Cst2510], [Cst2705], [Cst5010], [Cst7080], [Cst7120], [Cst7301])
) piv;
```

But it doesn't work. I get 1 "nvarchar to int"-error, while there is no NVARCHAR as field! Hours and Costs are FLOAT. All other are INT.

And I get an error like (my Studio is installed in English, but the error Msg is german) "In Pivot-Operator the value is wrong".

Please give me some hints ;-)

THX.

Greetz
Vegeta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not :

```
SELECT ReNr, sum(Hours), sum(Costs), 'Cost Center'
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 'Cost Center'
```

I see that you need sum over the Hours as well, so there are two SUMs.

Comment: And another time, I am thinking to complicated ;-) That is what I Need. THX :-)